# Efficient destination rectangle source rectangle clipping

Tags: c++, optimization

Each time I draw to a surface I need to be sure not to draw outside of the bounds. I have up to 262,144 draws in at a time. I cannot write or modify any of the underlying machine instructions. I need to clip source rectangles that are partially onscreen and its associated destination rectangle.

```
// return if dest_rect is entirely out bounds

// if dest_rect is partially inbounds modify src_rect and dest_rect accordingly

// draw without clipping if dest_rect is entirely inbounds
```

I will be using float based vector objects provided by the SDK to pick up on some hardware optimizations. I've seen some min max trickery in the past to help with similar problems and am unsure if I can write optimal code.

Edit* To be clear I am asking C++ advice on how to write an optimal clipping mechanism for the problem described. For example there might be an optimal logic to this, I am already aware of how to make code optimal by being const correct and maintaining optimal call stack size with inline function etc. Advice for example could cover only part of the question such has an optimal function for clipping.

*Edit
My current solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
float Clip(float _n, float _lower, float _upper)
{

    return std::max(_lower, std::min(_n, _upper));
}

void Iw2DImage::DrawClipped(CIwFVec2 _here, CIwFVec2 _bounds_xy, CIwFVec2 _bounds_wh) const
{
    // image is a region of texture atlas starting at xy with width and height wh

    // clip the destination region by the given bounds 
    const CIwFVec2 clipped_xy(
        Clip(_here.x,                _bounds_xy.x,   _bounds_xy.x + _bounds_wh.x),
        Clip(_here.y,                _bounds_xy.y,   _bounds_xy.y + _bounds_wh.y));
    const CIwFVec2 clipped_wh(
        Clip(_here.x + atlas_wh.x,   _bounds_xy.x,   _bounds_xy.x + _bounds_wh.x),
        Clip(_here.y + atlas_wh.y,   _bounds_xy.y,   _bounds_xy.y + _bounds_wh.y));

    // no point drawing an image with 0 width or height
    if (clipped_xy.x == clipped_wh.x) return;
    if (clipped_xy.y == clipped_wh.y) return;

    // change the source xy and wh by the same change in the destination region
    const CIwFVec2 clipped_atlas_xy(atlas_xy + (clipped_xy - _here));
    const CIwFVec2 clipped_atlas_wh(atlas_wh + (clipped_wh - (_here + atlas_wh)));

    /**
     * Draw a region of an image at 1:1 size at the specified location, modulated by the current colour, using the current alphamode
     * @param image the image to draw
     * @param topLeft the top left position of the image on the screen
     * @param regionOffset the top left of the region within the image
     * @param regionSize the size of the region within the image (and thus, on the screen)
     * @see Iw2DSetColour, Iw2DSetAlphaMode, Iw2DSetImageTransform
     * @par Required Header Files
     * Iw2D.h
     */
    Iw2DDrawImageRegion(i, clipped_xy, clipped_atlas_xy, clipped_atlas_wh);

}
```

Comment: what graphics library are you using?

Comment: This is for mobile devices and I do not have access to the SDK code. The SDK deploys to multiple platforms and there are elements of abstraction. I am using their draw image region function for drawing my images from my texture atlas. I do have the option of using almost raw open gl es but there could be allot of complications going that route, I think I will put up with the best performance I get out of their bare basics 2D drawing functions.

Comment: @user3345413 thnx, could you also post any code you have tried thus far?

Comment: @Jonny Henly I will post the code but it wont compile and has 2 bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but if you want to check if `src_rect` is inside your drawing area which has coordinates from `(0,0)` to `(dest_rect.width(), dest_rect.height())`, you could do something like

```
bool outOfBonds( src_rect, dest_rect )
{
   if( src_rect.X < 0 || src_rect.X + src_rect.Width() > dest_rect.width() )
      return true; //clipping on X axis
   else if( src_rect.Y < 0 || src_rect.Y + src_rect.Height() > dest_rect.Height() )
      return true; //clipping on Y axis

   return false;//No clipping
}
```

If you have two areas with random coordinates, and want to make sure `src_rect` is inside `dest_rect`, modify that to

```
bool outOfBonds( src_rect, dest_rect )
{
   if( src_rect.X < dest_rect.X || 
       src_rect.X + src_rect.Width() > dest_rect.X + dest_rect.width() )
   {
      return true; //clipping on X axis
   }
   else if( src_rect.Y < dest_rect.Y || 
            src_rect.Y + src_rect.Height() > dest_rect.Y +dest_rect.Height() )
   {
      return true; //clipping on Y axis
   }

   return false;//No clipping
}
```

Comment: Thanks If I do end up writing a generic clipping function I will consider what you gave me here.

Comment: I do define my co-ordinates, I could for example work with either xy + wh or xyA to xyB. I can change that based on which is more optimal.